# Manually enrolling Debian KEK

Tags: debian, uefi, secure-boot

I dual booted Ubuntu on my spare disk (next to main Ubuntu disk) to check if I am going to convert the main instance away from Ubuntu. One of the reasons I chose Debian is because it supports SecureBoot which I would prefer to keep and which was running nicely on Ubuntu.

My problem? My ASUS ROG Rampage V motherboard is borked, its one of the early SecureBoot motherboards and does not seem to support enrollment process, so none of the key enrollment utilities work on it. And based on asus support (or lack thereof) it seems it will not get it. Even with Ubuntu I had to manually enroll both Ubuntu KEK and my DB MOK key.

I wanted to do the same thing with Debian, however I cannot seem to find where Debian KEK key is located? **Does anyone know where it is or where I can obtain it from?** Presently I have MS and Canonical KEKs in my Mobo database (see below), and I would prefer to keep them and also install factory Debian KEK, not replace my database with fully custom keys (I might want to dual boot windows or Ubuntu later on, or simply reinstall Debian without too much hassle)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only Debian Secure Boot certificate I know of can be found here: https://dsa.debian.org/secure-boot-ca

According to Secure Boot specifications, if you delete the current PK, Secure Boot should transition into "Setup Mode" which should allow you to edit all the key variables  without signature requirements.

If you plan to take control of the firmware-level Secure Boot keys, replacing the PK with your own should be in your plans anyway.

The rules of Secure Boot are basically:

- If the bootloader's checksum can be found listed in `dbx`, it's a blacklisted bootloader and won't be executed.
- Otherwise, if the bootloader's checksum can be found listed in `db` or the bootloader is signed with a certificate that can be found in `db`, it will be executed.
- To modify `db` and/or `dbx` (for example, in order to provide blacklist updates), the updates should be signed with a certificate that can be found in `KEK`... unless `PK` does not exist, meaning that the platform is in Secure Boot Setup Mode and keys can be changed without restrictions.
- To modify `KEK`, the updates should be signed with a certificate that can be found in `PK`.. unless `PK` does not exist.
- There can be either zero or one `PK` certificates in the system, no more.

The Secure Boot shim bootloader `shimx64.efi` is designed to help in case the firmware Secure Boot variables cannot be modified. It is signed by Microsoft, and adds another category of keys, the `MOK`. When the shim bootloader is used, the MOK key(s) are basically equivalent to the `db` keys, but their administration is completely independent of the firmware and its possible bugs.

Comment: I am not planing on rolling out my own pk, ultimately I want to retain ASUS PK and MS KEK. One day I want to sell the Mobo and the buyer will probably want to install Windows on it. 
I am not sure KEK needs to be signed with PK. As you can see on my image, the Ubuntu KEK is installed and its a self signed cert (as is techncially the MS KEK as well). 
I am not sure about the purely software nature of MOKs either, before Ubuntu started loading my VMWare I had to enroll my MOK keys into eufi db, even though the system was booted from shimx64.efi

Comment: Some motherboards' UEFI settings may allow bypassing the rules laid down by the Secure Boot specification, but these rules are supposed to be enforced on all other software. If you don't replace the PK, then the only ways to manipulate the KEK keys will be through the UEFI settings. In my experience, Asus MBs typically have a way to reset the Secure Boot keys to factory defaults through the UEFI settings anyway.

Comment: I found a collection of public keys from rEFInd repository: https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/code/ci/master/tree/keys/